# How can I eager load on 3 different relationships in Laravel?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.6, eager-loading, laravel-5.7

I have 4 tables: `user`, `user_course`, `classes`, and `queues`.

`user_course` has a `user_id`, `classes` has a `user_course_id`, and `queues` has a `classes_id` column.

I'd like to retrieve all queues with a `class_id` that corresponds to a `user_course` registered by the current `user_id`.

Basically, what I want to do is: `$user->user_course->classes->queues`

Except I can't loop over the above directly.

So how can I eager load it with something like `$classes = App\Classes::with('Queues')` except constrain it to the currently logged in `user_id`?

I'm new to eager loading and can't get this to work. Please inform me if I need to edit my question details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$user = User::with('user_course.classes.queues')->find($idOfUser);
```

It will first run query to get user courses, then it will run query to get user courses classes and then it will run query the get queues of classes.